# How to prevent absolutely positioned child to being cropped by overflow hidden div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, absolute

I want to be able to show all the contents of the `divBox`, but it has to be inside `divBtoConteudo1_2`, as I have to make a reference to its position, in order to determine the right placement. The problem is the top layer, which is set to `overflow: hidden`, and it's not allowing to display the content.

```html
<div style="position: relative; display: block; width: 100vw; border-top: 1px solid #000000; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 100px;">
  <div id="divBtoConteudo1_2" style="position: relative; display: block; width: 725px; height: 100px; padding-left: 43px;">
    <!--Box.-->
    <div id="divBox" style="position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: -20px;">
      Box images.
    </div>
    <!--Box.-->
  </div>
</div>
```

I've researched a bit for this solution, but couldn't find anything that would work. And in some posts, it said even that it couldn't be done.

Is there any solution for this, even if I have to use some jQuery? It would be great if I only had to do some changes on the `divBox`, in order for it to work.

Comment: Why is `overflow:hidden` necessary? I am asking this to better understand the problem

Comment: Please provide a demo, your problem is not really clear

Comment: It´s part of a bigger structure, that needs for it to have this parameter...the real case code is a bit long, and I don´t think it will make it easier...but here it goes: http://memoriaweb.com.br.solidcp.temp-address.com/pt/LayoutPrincipal04.html
It´s under A memória web -> equipe

Answer (score 0):

do you try setting the style to style="visibility:hidden" or to style="display:none"

Answer (score 0):

try setting id="divBox" inline style z-index: 1000

I ran into this a lot in my projects

Comment: didn´t work...
     <div style="position: relative; display: block; width: 100vw; border-top: 1px solid #000000; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 100px;">
            <div id="divBtoConteudo1_2" style="position: relative; display: block; width: 725px; height: 100px; padding-left: 43px;">
                <!--Box.-->
                <div id="divBox" style="position: inline; display: block; top: 0px; margin-left: -50px; z-index: 1000;">
                    Box images. teste
                </div>
                <!--Box.-->
        
            </div>
        </div>